# Pass Gulp memory stream to gulp-connect

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-connect

How can I pass a memory stream to `gulp-connect` instead of creating files on a hard drive? I want to make `gulp-connect` serve files from memory.

```
gulp.src('style.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(rename('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')) // How prevent creating file on a hard drive
    .pipe(connect.reload()); // and serve files from memory?
```